# Searching Visual studio solution source code using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

**Requirement**
I have about 450 stored procedure names, stored in an excel file.
I need to generate a list of SPs which are not used (or called) in one large ASP.Net Solution.

**Approach**
I was thinking of using a PowerShell batch, if we have any kind of CmdLets or API which allow to search solution. If more that two references are found then we can safely conclude that the given SP is not used in solution.

**Areas where I seek help**

1. Do we have anything in powershell which allows us to search in VS Code via script.
2. Is there a better approcah to this problem?

Comment: Not necessarily use powershell. You can call `findstr /L /S /I /C:"SPName" *.cs` and parse its output using any language. Also you need to take care of SPs invoked by other SPs instead of ASP.NET code directly.

Comment: Thanks qxg, I'm trying it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.frm, *.ctl, *.bas, *.cls, *.vb,
 *.cs, *.txt, *.sql, *.fnc, *.csproj, *.vbproj, *.sln | Select-String 'search term'
```

Run the above from the root of your solution in a PowerShell prompt, replacing 'search term' with whatever you're looking for and you can also remove any -Include extensions that aren't in your solution.